# req.readyState==1 , How to change this?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I was trying to get `Priority Code` option set value of `Task` entity, using SOAP request.

```js
if (typeof (SDK) == "undefined")
{ SDK = { __namespace: true }; }

SDK.SOAPSamples = {
    _getServerUrl: function () {

        var OrgServicePath = "/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc/web";
        var serverUrl = "";
        if (typeof GetGlobalContext == "function") {
            var context = GetGlobalContext();
            serverUrl = context.getServerUrl();
        }
        else {
            if (typeof Xrm.Page.context == "object") {
                serverUrl = Xrm.Page.context.getServerUrl();
            }
            else
            { throw new Error("Unable to access the server URL"); }
        }
        if (serverUrl.match(/\/$/)) {
            serverUrl = serverUrl.substring(0, serverUrl.length - 1);
        }
        return serverUrl + OrgServicePath;
    },
    assignRequest: function (successCallback, errorCallback) {


        if (successCallback != null)
            this._parameterCheck(successCallback, "Function", "The SDK.SOAPSamples.assignRequest method successCallback parameter must be a function.");

        this._parameterCheck(errorCallback, "Function", "The SDK.SOAPSamples.assignRequest method errorCallback parameter must be a function.");

        var request = "POST https://tamaldomain.api.crm5.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc/web";
        request += "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8";
        request += "SOAPAction: http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services/IOrganizationService/Execute";

        request += "<s:Envelope xmlns:s='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>";
        request += "<s:Body>";
        request += "<Execute xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services' xmlns:i='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>";
        request += "<request i:type='a:RetrieveAttributeRequest' xmlns:a='http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts'>";
        request += "<a:Parameters xmlns:b='http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic'>";
        request += "<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
        request += "<b:key>MetadataId</b:key>";
        request += "<b:value i:type='c:guid' xmlns:c='http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/'>00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</b:value>";
        request += "</a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
        request += "<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
        request += "<b:key>RetrieveAsIfPublished</b:key>";
        request += "<b:value i:type='c:boolean' xmlns:c='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>false</b:value>";
        request += "</a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
        request += "<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
        request += "<b:key>EntityLogicalName</b:key>";
        request += "<b:value i:type='c:string' xmlns:c='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>task</b:value>";
        request += "</a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
        request += "<a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
        request += "<b:key>LogicalName</b:key>";
        request += "<b:value i:type='c:string' xmlns:c='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>prioritycode</b:value>";
        request += "</a:KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>";
        request += "</a:Parameters>";
        request += "<a:RequestId i:nil='true' />";
        request += "<a:RequestName>RetrieveAttribute</a:RequestName>";
        request += "</request>";
        request += "</Execute>";
        request += "</s:Body>";
        request += "</s:Envelope>";

        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open("POST", SDK.SOAPSamples._getServerUrl(), true)

        req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml, text/xml, */*");
        req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
        req.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services/IOrganizationService/Execute");
        req.onreadystatechange = function () { SDK.SOAPSamples.assignResponse(req, successCallback, errorCallback); };
        req.send(request);

    },
    assignResponse: function (req, successCallback, errorCallback) {
        debugger;
        if (req.readyState == 4) {
            if (req.status == 200) {
                if (successCallback != null)
                { successCallback(); }
            }
            else {
                errorCallback(SDK.SOAPSamples._getError(req.responseXML));
            }
        }
    }
```

The Problem is the value of `req.readyState` is 1, which means "server connection established". But I don't know whats exactly that means.

How I can change the value of `req.readyState` to 4 so that I can get response out of this request?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The onreadystatechange event is triggered five times (0-4), one time for each change in readyState. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp) more information about this states.

Comment: Hi Pedro, As u can see in code the vale of `req.readyState` must be 4 to execute `successCallback` function. Is there something wrong with this code?

Comment: No your code looks ok, but your never finish? Either in errorcallback? Try enable trace and see if it's done any error. When the request finish the value of readyState will be 4, so you can force anything.

Answer (score 0):

I find programming in javascript some situations cumbersome. So instead of using solely javascript I create a "Generic Handler" (.ashx) to program my solution and execute this handler from javascript using a XmlHttpRequest object.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving req to SDK.SOAPSamples scope and then use it in assignResponse like this:

```
SDK.SOAPSamples = {
    req: null,
    _getServerUrl: function () { … },
    assignRequest: function (successCallback, errorCallback) { 
        //...           
        var req = SDK.SOAPSamples.req = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        //...
    },
    assignResponse: function (successCallback, errorCallback) { //remove req param
        var req = SDK.SOAPSamples.req;

        if (req.readyState == 4) {
        if (req.status == 200) {
        if (successCallback != null) { successCallback(); }}
        else { errorCallback(SDK.SOAPSamples._getError(req.responseXML));}}
    }
}
```